# SQL Select Query Using variable to fetch row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that lists activities for every day of the week in separate columns of a table "profile" named "monday", "tuesday"...etc. I want to load that data by setting a variable $day to date("l"), which should return the day of the week. My database connection works, and the query loads the day of the week when I add the specific day to the fetch array, for example - $row['monday'] shows activity for monday;. When I try to use the variable $day to load the associated day $row['$day'], the results are 0. How do I use my variable to load results from that column. - if today is Tuesday, when I enter username and pin, the Tuesday column loads from that users row.

```
  <form action="" method="post" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="username">User Name:</label>
 <input type="username" class="form-control" name="userName">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="pin">Pin:</label>
 <input type="pin" class="form-control" name="pin">
 </div>


 <button type="submit" name="submit"  
 class="btn btn default">Submit</button>
 </form> 


 <?php 
 $day = date("l");   

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {



 include('util.php'); 



 $userName = $_POST['userName']; 
 $pin = $_POST['pin']; 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE userName = '$userName' 
 AND pin = '$pin'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Activity: " . $row['$day']. "<br>" ;
 }
 } else {
 echo "0 results";
 }
 $conn->close();



 }

 ?>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables don't expand in [single-quoted strings](https://php.net/language.types.string).  So when you do this:

```
$row['$day']
```

You're literally looking for a column called "$day", which doesn't exist in the row.  You could do this:

```
$row["$day"]
```

Which would expand the variable.  But it's not really necessary.  The variable is itself the string you want to use, so just use it as what it is:

```
$row[$day]
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT $day FROM profile WHERE userName = '$userName' AND pin = '$pin'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Activity: " . $row["$day"]. "<br>" ;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

Comment: @eazyduzit100: Please note also that your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You're going to want to investigate using prepared statements instead of just executing user input as code.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! This is just for a group of friends, but I welcome ways to expand my PHP skills, so thank you and will do!